# search folder value when creating task group for release pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, nunit, azure-pipelines

I have created a task group for build pipeline. One of the steps in it is "Publish Build Artifacts" with path to publish as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and "Artifact publish location" as "Azure Pipelines/TFS" (the other option being "A file share".

Once my build is successful, I want to "release". I created a new set of task group to first install NUnit Console runner, than Install NUnit3 Test adapter (both powershell scripts).

My next step is to run "Visual Studio Test Platform Installer" after which I want to run all my tests to make sure they are passing. In this step one of the required parameters is "Search Folder".

If I give it the value `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, it works fine. But it feels like I should be using a variable that's specific to the build and not system level.

Can someone please clarify what I should be using? Am I thinking right that the system level variable would be too low and I should be using something closer to the build artifacts? when I use `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`, it fails saying it could not find my test dlls.

Comment: The tests are part of the build or the release?

Comment: They are unit tests in my solution. I am running it in both build and release. This problem I am facing is in release. In build I am able to find and execute them using $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

Comment: In release pipeline you can't use build variables. what is the issue with System.Default...? it's the folder where the artifacts downloaded.

Comment: so if there is multiple pipelines, it would know which artifact to use based on the one selected when setting up "Agent job" --> Artifact download?

Comment: yea, it's ok, in each pipeline the variable value will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep use the variable `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`, is not "system" scope variable, in each pipeline the value will point to correct artifacts.

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables).